# Dynamic Mail Forwarding Based on Superscription Table

Tags: php, mysql, perl, email, forwarding

Client asked this morning if we can provide a subscription service whereby:

1. Mail arives to a specific address on a cloud mail server with no procmail/maildrop possibilities
2. Cron runs Perl or PHP script on another server which checks for new mail and based on address mail ***purports*** to be from, does a subscriber look up, and forwards the email ***with any attachments*** to all subscribers along with an added unsubscribe link
3. Script deletes forwarded email

Mail server will have both IMAP and POP access, apparently.

// EDIT
Note that mail will be from 220+ governmental agencies/organizations.  Users will use interface to specify which organizations they wish to receive forwards from.  In order to run like a traditional mailing list we'd have to set up 200 mailing lists and then make an interface to handle subscriptions.  The proposed interface will allow 1 - 200 subscriptions with a single opt-in confirmation email and a single opt-out interface.
// END EDIT

Client has been warned that header spoofing is child's play and that viral attachments are a serious concern and is willing to proceed nonetheless.

So, with the caveat that this is NOT an idea that I endorse what libraries have you used to accomplish this sort of task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not mention what kind of mail server you are dealing with. Perl has [Net::IMAP::Client](http://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aIMAP%3a%3aClient) and [Net::POP3](http://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aPOP3) to handle fetching mail.

For sending email using an SMTP server, there is [Email::Sender](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Email%3a%3aSender%3a%3aManual%3a%3aQuickStart) or [Net::SMTP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net%3a%3aSMTP) or [Net::SMTP::SSL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net%3a%3aSMTP%3a%3aSSL).

At a minimum, you'll need an email account which you can use to send emails (this might be the original account that receives the messages).

In between fetching and sending, you can check for spam using [Spam Assassin](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mail-SpamAssassin) and for viruses using [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net).

I don't know why the original messages need to be deleted, but at the very least, I would log every single step in detail.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sinan!  Apparently I'll have access to POP and IMAP.  Looking at the CPAN synopses for both I don't see methods for sending mail or more specifically for forwarding email.  Do you know if they can forward a received email with its attachments?

Comment: I would additionally check any attachments against an antivirus program given that you're basically re-sending whatever arrives onto a bunch of people. Some overhead but will proabably be worth your while.

Comment: POP and IMAP are indeed receiving-end mailbox access protocols. You will additionally need an SMTP client for sending / forwarding messages. If you have shell access on the mail server itself, you could use a local script or Procmail instead of POP or IMAP.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is a [mailing list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_mailing_list).  If at all possible, you should look into using one of the several existing software packages designed for managing such lists, such as [majordomo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majordomo_%28software%29), [ezmlm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ezmlm) or [mailman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Mailman), rather than trying to roll your own.

Comment: I understand that this resembles a mailing list however it will be used for individuals to select as many as 220 organizations from which they would like to receive forwards with each organization representing a separate list.  It seems unmanageable to use a typical mailing list package to manage these.